# is there a way to save an image as pdf with cmyk-colour scheme?

Tags: php

I have to save a file to go the printer, and ideally it would be a pdf with cmyk. Is there a way to do this? Right now I have an image file, but now it has to be saved manually...

Comment: Have you already checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241282/converting-pdf-to-cmyk-with-identify-recognizing-cmyk ?

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick can convert image formats to PDF, and PHP has a well-documented plugin for working with it. As for whether ImageMagick itself can generate CMYK PDF files, I'm not sure as it's not something I've had to do myself, but this should at least get you headed in the right direction.