# How can I convert a PDF to CMYK with different kinds of black?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, inkscape, cmyk

I have a PDF that I created in Inkscape. I would like to convert it to CMYK for a printing company, but I have one issue - I want to convert some blacks to "rich black" (20/20/20/100) and others to "flat black" (0/0/0/100). I have 60 cards and would like to automate this rather than having to do it manually for each file. How can I do this?

Specifically, the card has text and design elements on it that shouldn't be rich black because they're too small and detailed, but the printing company suggests that since the border is solid black that part should be rich black. I've managed to convert my PDF to CMYK by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241282/converting-pdf-to-cmyk-with-identify-recognizing-cmyk) but all the blacks seem to be rich.

Comment: Use a different program to assign your black colors. You could group the objects with the same black together to more easily find them, e.g. in Scribus.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you haven't said what criteris you want to use to differentiate between your types of black, how do you propose to instruct the application **which** objects drawn in 'black' should be converted to pure K, and which ones should be a mixture of CMYK ?

You don't say what the input colour space is either.

Ghostscript's pdfwrite device does not distinguish between object type, you can (with effort) use a customised ICC profile to create a pure K output from a given input space and colour value but there's no way to say "I want to use this profile for this bit of the file, but this other profile for this other bit of the file".

Also, this isn't (as written) a programming question.