# Ghostscript print driver to force cmyk instead of rgb?

Tags: printing, driver, ghostscript

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I'd like to know if Ghostscript could be used to create a print driver for an HP color laser printer to make it print cmyk instead of its native rgb profile?

If not, is there any other way to force an HP laser printer to print in cmyk?

Comment: All laser printers I know about convert an RGB color to CMYK automatically. The printer knows when asked to print an RGB color how to approximate the color in the print engine with CMYK colored toners. Do you want to read the RGB ps or pdf with ghostscript and write a new ps or pdf with CMYK? Please explain.

Comment: Here are some answers: [converting-pdf-to-cmyk-with-identify-recognizing-cmyk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241282/converting-pdf-to-cmyk-with-identify-recognizing-cmyk?rq=1)