# Using GhostScript to convert (any) PDF using a certain ICC profile for output?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, color-management

I use (Lua)LaTeX to create a PDF for printing. The color workflow is not well-managed: The PDF contains CMYK-colored LaTeX elements, PDF figures created in Inkscape, and RGB photos. ImageMagick's `identify` tool reveals that all pages are in the sRGB color space (which [may or may not be significant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241282/converting-pdf-to-cmyk-with-identify-recognizing-cmyk)). Lacking Adobe software and its Preflight feature, I tried to use GhostScript to convert my PDF file. A print shop is likely to provide a certain ICC profile for the colors that the PDF will need to be compliant with. So, having read up on [color management in GhostScript](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GhostscriptColorManagement.html#usage) and some related questions here, I came up with the following script using GhostScript 10.01.1 (on Windows 10 64-bit):

```
gswin64c ^
  -o "output.pdf" ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -dAutoRotatePages=/None ^
  -dRenderIntent=0 ^
  -sOutputICCProfile=ISOcoated_v2_bas.ICC ^
  "input.pdf"
```

The call fails with `undefined in .putdeviceprops` and a stack of `.putdeviceprops  --nostringval--  unknownerror`. Being fairly new to the GhostScript world, online research would not yield reasonable results without having to dive into implementation details of GhostScript. So, troubleshooting revealed that the `-sOutputICCProfile` line is the problematic one, although it seemed to be the straighforward option. Using another profile yields the same error.

If I use the (apparently deprecated) option `-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK` instead, GhostScript runs and produces a PDF in CMYK with color separation (according to ImageMagick's `identify`), but some and especially green-ish colors in the PDF are far off the intended color. This cannot be a solution anyway since, as said, I have to use whatever ICC profile will be given to me.

**So here are the questions**: Is it true that GhostScript converts the PDF colors to a perceptual space (i.e., CIE), and then to the output profile? Why is the `-sOutputICCProfile` breaking the call? How can I get GhostScript to use a certain ICC profile for the converted PDF?

Also, this is just the beginning of what I'm trying to accomplish. If the print shop would require the file to be PDF-X compliant, would I need to alter how the color space is ensured?

Comment: " Is it true that GhostScript converts the PDF colors to a perceptual space (i.e., CIE), and then to the output profile?" No. The pdfwrite device goes to some lengths to make the output the same as the input. The -sOutputICCProfile only has effect on rendering devices and pdfwrite is not a rendering device. I don't know where you got the idea the ColorConversionStrategy is deprecated; it is **not**. If you want to produce colour managed output then you need to use that switch **and** supply the ICC profile as the DefaultCMYK profile to pdfwrite.

Comment: The pdfwrite device can produce PDF/X-3 files https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/VectorDevices.html#creating-a-pdf-x-3-document. Ignore the ProcessColorModel (I need to get the docs updated there).

Comment: An alternative is to use the pdfimage operators, which will render the content to an image, obeying all the colour management stuff you reference (which pdfwrite ignores) and produce a final PDF file containing the image. Of course it will be large and unscalable, but it will be colour managed.