# Converting (any) PDF to black (K)-only CMYK

Tags: pdf, cmyk

This is related to:

- [Converting PDF to CMYK (with identify recognizing CMYK).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241282/converting-pdf-to-cmyk-with-identify-recognizing-cmyk)
- [Script (or some other means) to convert RGB to CMYK in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418268/script-or-some-other-means-to-convert-rgb-to-cmyk-in-pdf)

... but a bit more specific here: say I have an RGB PDF, where the text color is "rich black" (R:0 G:0 B:0 gone to C:100 M:100 Y:100 K:100), and diverse images and vector graphics.

I would like to convert this to a CMYK PDF, using a free command line tool (so it is batch scriptable under Linux), which

- has contents *only* in the black (K) channel:

  - Preserves vector graphics (+ text glyphs) - colors become grayscale in black (K) channel only
  - Images get converted to grayscale in black (K) channel only

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted in my comment to @Mark Storer, it turns out that forcing a gray print only on the K plate in CMYK, may not be so trivial ... I guess it depends much on what is being used as "preflight" preview device - for Linux, the only thing I can find is `ghostscript` with `tiffsep`, which is what I use for 'sanity check' regarding CMYK separations.

Anyways, I got a lot of help in this thread on `comp.lang.postscript`:

- [PDF to PDF (gs?): rich RGB black to plain K (CMYK) black? - comp.lang.postscript | Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.postscript/browse_thread/thread/7ffbdd6b8d6fd8f9/5f35d2954d1fe71c#5f35d2954d1fe71c)

... and one workflow that works for me is:

- Convert PDF to PS using `ghostscript`'s `ps2write`
- Use `ghostscript` to convert this PS back to PDF, while executing replacement functions in [HackRGB-cmyk-inv.ps](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/ps/HackRGB-cmyk-inv.ps)
- Use `ghostscript`'s `tiffsep` to check actual separations

In respect to, say, this PDF generated by OpenOffice: [blah-slide.pdf](http://sdaaubckp.sf.net/post/img/blah-slide.pdf), the command lines would be:

```
# PDF to PS using `ps2write` device of `ghostscript`
gs \
   -dNOPAUSE \
   -dBATCH \
   -sDEVICE=ps2write \
   -sOutputFile=./blah-slide-gsps2w.ps \
    ./blah-slide.pdf 

# PS to PDF using replacement function in HackRGB-cmyk-inv.ps
gs \
   -dNOPAUSE \
   -dBATCH \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=./blah-slide-hackRGB-cmyk-inv.pdf \
    ./HackRGB-cmyk-inv.ps \
    ./blah-slide-gsps2w.ps

# check separations
gs \
   -dNOPAUSE \
   -dBATCH \
   -dSAFER \
   -sDEVICE=tiffsep \
   -dFirstPage=1 \
   -dLastPage=1 \
   -sOutputFile=p%02d.tif \
    blah-slide-hackRGB-cmyk-inv.pdf \
\
&& eog p01.tif 2>/dev/null
```

This should only work on RGB values where R=G=B (and hopefully grayscale values), and only on text colors, and it also flattens text information  - but it should be possible to confirm via `tiffsep` that the text indeed ends up only on the K plate.

As mentioned in the newsgroup post, this is not extensively tested, but looks promising so far...
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As an improvement to sdaau's great answer, I can recommend using pdftops from [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) for converting pdf to ps, instead of ghostscript ps2write, because the latter e.g. causes the font to become staircasey, and is said to not preserve the original pdf accurately. Compare by zooming into text areas of the resulting pdfs.

Comment: Many thanks for that answer, @Ole - great to have an alternative here... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you convert the PDF using GS twice.  Once to a Shades Of Gray colorspace, and then to CMYK.

I'm not sure it'll work, but I'd be a bit surprised if it didn't.  G->CMYK sounds like a brain-dead `X -> 0 0 0 X` conversion.  At least if you stick to "device gray" and "device CMYK" instead of some calibrated color space that'll tweak things this way and that.

Comment: Hi @Mark Storer, thanks for the answer! I guess, demonstrating that the G->CMYK conversions could be a matter of which device renders the final display; I use `gs` with `tiffsep` for (I guess) "preflight", and usually, just a RGB->G->CMYK will show text black on all four plates, just like when viewing the original RGB "preflight". However, I got some answers on `comp.lang.postscript`, which I'm going to post about next...