# Convert pdf to other formats with colorprofiles using ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, file-conversion

I'm planning to use colorprofiles while converting pdf's to jpg/png/pdf(low res/high res/rgb/cmyk) but (**Question 1**)I could not find how could I determine if a input document has an icc profile and if it has do i use it to help my conversion. Is there a ghostscript command to determine icc profiles

I found a gs command to convert to pdf as below from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591554/embed-icc-color-profile-in-pdf/31593330):

```
gs -o cmyk-doc.pdf      \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite    \
   -dOverrideICC=true   \
   -sDefaultCMYKProfile=/path/to/mycmykprofile.icc \
   -sOutputICCProfile=/path/to/mydeviceprofile.icc \
   -dRenderIntent=3     \
   -dDeviceGrayToK=true \
    input-doc.pdf
```

(**Question 2**)If my input document has a profile, can I skip the option -sDefaultCMYKProfile and only pass the required -sOutputICCProfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Ghostscript to determine if a PDF file has ICC colour profiles. Note there can be **numerous** colour profiles in a PDF file. Each colour can be in its own space, and each space can use a different ICC colour profile. That's in addition to the OutputIntent profile. On the other hand, you don't need to care.

For rendering you are basically looking at a conversion like this:

input colour -> CIE representation -> output colour

The input colour (in PDF) can be Gray, RGB, CMYK, Separation, DeviceN or one of the CIE spaces; Lab, ICC.

The output colour, for rendering will need to be one of Gray, RGB, CMYK or 'separated' (where each component rendered to a separate gray image).

The OutputICCProfile controls the second half of that conversion, the Default* profiles control the first half of that conversion, when the colour space isn't already one of the CIE spaces.

Taking question 2 first....

You never need to supply the DefaultCMYKProfile. That is used to override the Ghostscript default CMYK->CIE profile. You can use this if you happen to know that the input file is in CMYK space, and that it was a characterised CMYK space. In which case supplying the profile for that space would do a better job of converting from CMYK to CIE than the Ghostscript default one. However this is rare and generally only true in controlled workflows.

For question 1:

You only really care if the PDF file does **not** contain ICC profiles but instead defines colours in a device space such as RGB or CMYK. In that case, and assuming the PDF file has been created for a colour controlled workflow, you might assume that all the colours are in the same space, in which case I believe you would want to use the OutputIntent profile from the PDF file, or override the Ghostscript default (see below). There is extensive documentation on the use of ICC profiles [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/Use.htm#ICC_color_parameters).

The OutputICCProfile is used with rendering devices in order to characterise the output space. So if you are rendering to RGB output you might use a specific RGB ICC profile to convert from CIE space to RGB space. That profile might additionally then be attached to the output file (eg JPEG) and a conforming reader would be able to use that profile to convert the RGB samples back into CIE space in order to use yet another profile to convert to a different characterised space (eg the profile for your display).

Now that's for **rendering**, ie creating a bitmap image. The pdfwrite device, on the other hand, goes to considerable lengths to maintain input colours in their original colour space. If you want to convert them into a different space then you need to set -sColorConversionStrtaegy. The command line you've quoted won't do that. If you want it converted to a characterised CMYK space then you would indeed supply the OutputICCProfile, but you do need to specify -sColorConversionStrategy=DeviceCMYK.